# MySQL suddenly breaks and returns 'ERROR: Could not connect. Connection refused'

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, bitnami

I was recently learned that the account sign-up/sign-in section on part of my website recently broke. This is what I saw when visiting the webpage:

```sql
ERROR: Could not connect. Connection refused
```

Upon further investigation, the below MySQL error seems to be the culprit:

```sql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

By the way, `mysqld` returns errors:

```sql
mysqld: Can't open shared library '/opt/bitnami/mysql/plugin/component_reference_cache.so' (errno:
 13 /opt/bitnami/mysql/plugin/component_reference_cache.so: cannot open shared object file: No suc
h file or directory)
mysqld: Cannot load component from specified URN: 'file://component_reference_cache'.
2021-09-15T00:19:36.709416Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 
8.0.23) starting as process 20897
2021-09-15T00:19:36.735023Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is cur
rently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future releas
e. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
2021-09-15T00:19:36.735037Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_general_ci'
 is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an app
ropriate collation instead.
2021-09-15T00:19:36.758178Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /opt/bitnami/m
ysql/data/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-09-15T00:19:36.758210Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 beca
use file system for /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2021-09-15T00:19:36.767154Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/opt/bitnami/mysql
/logs/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
2021-09-15T00:19:36.768341Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-09-15T00:19:36.786406Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdow
n complete (mysqld 8.0.23)  Source distribution.
```

I tried figuring out how to fix the error, and to find out why it happened. I did some research, but I could not find anything that was useful enough. This error is a surprise, as this error happened suddenly, even though few people visit my website and I was not working on this section of my website recently.

If you know why this is going on and how to fix it, please share it with me below.

Comment: Have you checked if your mysqld is down or if your connecting to the right socket? You don't specify what you've tried

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, I can see several errors in the information you posted. First of all, I can see that MySQL is returning errors when trying to open the log file, did you edit the permissions? You can launch a fresh instance and compare the permissions configuration to try to solve the problem. Apart from that, I can see that I can see that the socket's path is wrong (`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`), that file must be inside the /opt/bitnami folder. Did you change the configuration of the database recently?

Comment: No, I did not do anything with that part of my website recently or change anything with the database.